# How to write mapPropertyM for QuickCheck's PropertyM?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, quickcheck

I want to write a function `mapPropertyM :: (m a -> n a) -> PropertyM m a -> PropertyM n a` for the [`PropertyM`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.2/QuickCheck-2.8.1/Test-QuickCheck-Monadic.html#t:PropertyM) monad. I've tried for a while to do this, but I end up getting very confused unwrapping and wrapping with the higher order functions.

Comment: @nobody could you give me more details about where that could help? It's a big library, and to me it seems most of the monadic stuff is related to MTL monads, which this is not.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, you can use `fmap` to define `mapPropertyM`  function, right? If you're looking for alternatives, you may use lens.

Comment: You cannot because `m` appears in both a covariant and contravariant position. Also the type variable `a` is not used "inside" of an `m` so it doesn't make sense to have a function of type `m a -> n a` as input at at all. Try writing a function of type `(m Property -> n Property) -> (n Property -> m Property) -> PropertyM m a -> Property n a`.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by the "covariant and contravariant position"? Is there somewhere I can go to in order to find more information about this?